# Symfony querybuilder subquery using sprintf() and alias

Tags: php, symfony, orm

I'm trying to make a "complex" (for me) querybuilder. Here is the basic SQL request:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fif.idfichefrais, fif.idvisiteur, fif.date, fif.nbjustificatifs, fif.montantvalide, fif.datemodif, fif.idetat, montantTotalFraisForfait, montantTotalFraisHorsForfait, libelleFraisHorsForfait
FROM FicheFrais fif
INNER JOIN (SELECT lff.idfichefrais, SUM(frf.montantFraisForfait*lff.quantite) as montantTotalFraisForfait
            FROM LigneFraisForfait AS lff
            INNER JOIN FraisForfait AS frf ON frf.idfraisforfait = lff.idfraisforfait
            GROUP BY lff.idfichefrais) a USING (idfichefrais)
INNER JOIN (SELECT e.idetat, e.libelleEtat
            FROM Etat AS e) b USING (idetat)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT lfhf.idfichefrais, SUM(lfhf.montant) as montantTotalFraisHorsForfait, lfhf.libelle as libelleFraisHorsForfait
            FROM LigneFraisHorsForfait AS lfhf
            GROUP BY lfhf.idfichefrais) c USING (idfichefrais)
WHERE fif.idvisiteur = '?' 
AND YEAR(fif.date) ='?'
ORDER BY MONTH(fif.date) ASC;
```

and here is my querybuilder that I'm trying to accomplish

```
public function findFicheFraisByIdVisiteurAndAnnee($idvisiteur, $annee): array
    {
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $a = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $b = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $c = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

        $selectFraisForfait = $a->select(array('lff.idfichefrais, SUM(frf.montantFraisForfait*lff.quantite)'))
                            ->from('App:Lignefraisforfait', 'lff')
                            ->innerJoin('App:Fraisforfait', 'frf', Join::WITH, 'frf.idfraisforfait = lff.idfraisforfait')
                            ->groupBy('lff.idfichefrais');

        $selectEtat = $b->select(array('e.idetat, e.libelleEtat ad libelleFraisHorsForfait'))
                            ->from('App:Etat', 'e');
        
        $selectFraisHorsForfait = $c->select(array('lfhf.idfichefrais, SUM(lfhf.montant) as montantTotalFraisHorsForfait'))
                            ->from('App:Lignefraishorsforfait','lfhf')
                            ->groupBy('lfhf.idfichefrais');

        return $FicheFraisByIdVisiteurAndAnnee = $qb
            ->select(array('fif.idfichefrais, identity(fif.idvisiteur) as idvisiteur, fif.date, fif.nbjustificatifs, fif.montantvalide, fif.datemodif, identity(fif.idetat) as idetat,montantTotalFraisForfait, montantTotalFraisHorsForfait, libelleFraisHorsForfait'))
            ->from('App:Fichefrais', 'fif')
            ->innerJoin('App:Lignefraisforfait', sprintf('($s)selectfraisforfait', $selectFraisForfait->getDQL()), Join::WITH, 'fif.idfichefrais = selectfraisforfait.idfichesfrais')
            ->innerJoin('App:Etat', sprintf('($s)selectetat', $selectEtat->getDQL()), Join::WITH, 'fif.idetat = selectetat.idetat')
            ->leftJoin('App:Lignefraishorsforfait', sprintf('($s)selectFraisHorsForfait', $selectFraisHorsForfait->getDQL()), Join::WITH, 'fif.idfichefrais = selectfraishorsforfait.idfichefrais')
            ->where('fif.idvisiteur = :idvisiteur')
            ->setParameter('idvisiteur' , $idvisiteur)
            ->andWhere('YEAR(fif.date) = :annee')
            ->setParameter('annee', $annee)
            ->groupBy('fif.idfichefrais')
            ->groupBy('lfhf.idfichefrais')
            ->orderBy('MONTH(fif.date)', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(12)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()

        ;
    }
```

Comment: You apparently don't intend to retrieve entities, so why bother with a query builder if you already have the raw SQL? https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-queries/raw-sql-queries

Comment: well, it's because i wanna know how to use querybuilder and i do like it ! i could just use direct SQL but i just like how querybuilder looks and works, and i wanna make it work to use it everytime, and i do retrieve entities, i just add custom private and methods to my entities withtout any comments then my findby methods are not obstructed by new private that don't exist in the database specialy with twig, it is wonderfull. i really want that query to work the way the sql does :c.